# Remove plot outer axises, without removing the subplot axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to have the following plot to appear like the second plot.
Without the axises (vertical, horizontal) that have no meaning for this plot and range from 0 to 1.

[image: Original output]
[image: Desired output]

This is the code I'm using to generate to plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x_lim = (0, 1)
y_lim = (0, 1)
z_lim = (0, 1)
list_points = [[0.3, 0.3, 0], [0.4, 0.4, 0], [0, 0, 0], [.1, .1, .5], [0.3, 0.3, .2]]

def plot_tracking_map():
    """
    Visualize all grapes centers on a 3d map.
    This function generates a plot that represents the TB in 3D.
    """
    x_cors, y_cors, z_cors = [], [], []
    for i in range(len(list_points)):
        x_cor, y_cor, z_cor = list_points[i][0], list_points[i][1], list_points[i][2]
        x_cors.append(x_cor)
        y_cors.append(y_cor)
        z_cors.append(z_cor)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
    yy, zz = np.meshgrid(range(2), range(2))
    xx = yy
    s = ax.scatter(x_cors, y_cors, z_cors, s=400, marker='o')  # x,y,z coordinates, size of each point, colors.
    # controls the alpha channel. all points have the same value, ignoring their distance
    s.set_edgecolors = s.set_facecolors = lambda *args: None
    ax.title.set_text(f'Imgae number 1')
    plt.show()

plot_tracking_map()
```

**edit**

I changed the lines

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
```

to

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12), subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
```

And it solved the problem.

Comment: You could use `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))` instead of `fig, ax = plt.subplots(...)` to avoid creating a dummy unused subplot.  Or you could directly use `fig, ax= plt.subplots(figsize=..., subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})`without the need for `fig.add_subplot(....)`.

Comment: Thanks! The second option was the easier solution and solved my problem.